# Derallieur capacity

Tags: cassette

I was jus looking at options for when I have to replace my cassette, A shimano Sora HG50 9 Speed casstte, there is option for a 12-27 or a 11-34, the 11-34 will give me more range but I am near to 100% sure that I have a short cage derailleur so I ask if this 11-34 will fit or will it prove to be too much for it and if so would a derailleur hanger extender solve this problem?
For context, I live in the surrey hills and climb quite a few steep hills on each ride and my nearest is maxes out at 25%, a good example of where I would like to spin an easier gear.
Thanks

Comment: What RD do you have? Not all short-cage RDs are the same. Even Sora RDs differ between generations.

Comment: The "medium" Sora cage that I have can handle 34, and isn't very expensive. 9-speed MTB derailleurs are compatible too, and may come in cheaper (I was looking on SJS earlier)

Comment: Thanks Chris H !

Answer (score 2):

34 is likely too much. Nowadays short-cage Shimano RDs tend to allow 28 and 32 could somehow work, as the specs are very conservative, but 34 is likely too much. The extender should work, but the shifting will not be that precise.

Comment: Ok, I see, so the extender affects the shifting performance Thanks